# value of X and Y from triangle

Tags: triangles

my son is in 6th grade and i am trying to help him solve this problem. but i want to understand so i can teach him.

Write and solve equations to determine the value of x and y .

triangle is given (PMN).

> $M$ is $13x$, $N$ is 65 deg, $p$ is not given. length pm is 7/8in, MN not
>   given, $PN$ is $Y+2/3$ in.

I watched some youtube videos but can't find one that is suitable for 6th grader. Please see attached.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One relation you can use is that the angles sum to $180^\circ$.
$$
180 = \alpha + 65 + (13 x)
$$
I would split the angle $\alpha$, and the side $MN$, such that we get two rectangular triangles.

Interesting Deepaks remark about the dashes indicating a triangle with two equal sides seems to be true in the English speaking world, I see it used in the [English language Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isosceles_triangle) (but not in the German one). The word isocles shows up in another problem on that image as well so it looks likely.

That simplifies the problem a lot. We have
$$
7/8 = y + 2/3
$$
and split $\alpha$ in the middle.
So the relation for the other two angles gets very easy.

Answer (score 0):

You know the triangle is isoceles (that's what those little dashes across the sides mean) with $PM = PN$.

Two properties of an isoceles triangle are important here.

1) two sides are equal in length - can you set up an equation involving $y$ that can be easily solved?

2) the two base angles are equal - can you set up an equation involving $x$ that can be easily solved?